# Subset of null set (set of measure zero)

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Is there a proper subset of a set of measure zero that is not measurable?

Any examples? Thanks a lot!

I suspect the answer is yes due to some careful phrasing in books, e.g. let F be a subset of a null set in A. If F were always measurable, it would be simpler to say let F be a null set instead.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a phrasing from your text? This seems unusual, given that the answer to your question is no.

Comment: One way to see that the answer is no is to note that Lebesgue measure can be defined via "inner measure" and "outer measure", and that the outer measure of a subset is necessarily smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, in general, depends on the $\sigma$-algebra you choose.

For instance, if we take our measure space to be $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{A}, \lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $\mathscr{A} =\{A: \forall B, \lambda^*(B) = \lambda^*(A\cap B) + \lambda^*(A^c \cap B) \}$ is the set of all measurable (in the sense of Caratheodory's criterion) subsets, the answer is **no**. Clearly from the definition of $\mathscr{A}$, if $A$ is measurable and has measure $0$, and $A' \subseteq A$, then $\lambda^*(B) = \lambda^*(A' \cap B) + \lambda^*(A^c \cap B) = 0 + \lambda^*(B)$ and so $A' \in \mathscr{A}$.

However, if we take $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$ where again $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, then the answer is **yes**, though you NEED the axiom of choice in order to find one. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32720/non-borel-sets-without-axiom-of-choice.

Answer (score 3):

For Lebesgue Measure on $\mathbb{R}$, the answer is decisively **no**. The reason is Caratheodory's Theorem: Lebesgue measure is constructed as the completion of a premeasure, and this theorem guarantees that the set $\mathcal{M}$ of measurable sets under the premeasure is a $\sigma$-algebra, and the measure restricted to $\mathcal{M}$ is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure). See also Folland's *Real Analysis* Chapter 1.